# Kill all currently opened connections in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, networking, asynchronous

Is there a possibility to kill all current network connections in node.js app?

The reason:
I have an node.js app that makes A LOT OF parralel network requests with timeout. I am searching for an option for aborting my async threads or just killing connections so that theese threads would timeout and stop executing.

The problem:
After I launch about thousand async network requests with 10 seconds timeout I am unable to fetch info from localhost for about 30 seconds. I think this can be because node.js or OS connection pool is overloaded. So node is waiting until that threads timeout, than maybe until garbage collector frees space for new connections and only then makes connection for localhost.

I want to have STOP button in my app that kills/stops all that connections (or any app connections) and makes instant connection to localhost. How I can do that with node.js and javascript?

I cannot chain my async functions because I need to run them in parallel mode. The only solution I know now is to limit parallel connections by 100, so I have space for connection to localhost, but this makes whole process slow and why I should do that? Why I can't spawn thouthand of network threads and then just force stop them and do another task instantly? Why I should wait for tcp timeout of that connections?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is feasible in your case but you could make those requests through a child process. That way you can selectively kill the connections with lower priority and so on.

Comment: What about setting timeouts for the requests, and using something like `async.parallelLimit()` to limit the volume?

Comment: @galactocalypse Wow, this is a good idea, I may kill the whole process to kill connections, but I need to get data back to main app. I am doing it from callback now, the callback is updating the model. Is it possible to run connections through child process and update model from there?

Comment: @remus I am already using timeouts. I just dont want to wait for timeouts to burn out because it takes about 10-20 seconds. I already said that using parallellimit is not an option because it makes whole process slow. I want to make it work full throttle and then completely stop when I want. After years of synchronous programming I am a bit unsatisfied with some workarounds I should do in node. But it still the best thing I can find to do desktop apps.

Comment: Gotcha. Galacto's suggestion is a great one. Try http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn

Comment: It is possible to update the model from the child process, but not always advisable. What you can do is ask for any pending data before killing the child process. Since it's event-based, this shouldn't incur any waiting.

Comment: Thanks all, I will try to implement that and post my answer